# How to get a key from a specific database row when I double click an item on a list?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

Basically I have this list of students (alunos) and I want to double click in one of the students and I want it to show a MessageBox containing:

```
Student No.: {student no. from the selected student here}
Name: {student name from the selected student here}
etc...
```

Here's the code I have:

```
void lstAlunos_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM (" +
                "SELECT" +
                "ROW_NUMBER() AS rownumber," +
                "columns" +
                "FROM Alunos" +
                ") AS foo" +
                "WHERE rownumber = " + lstAlunos.SelectedIndex;

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                connection.Open();

                reader.Read();
                string numAluno = reader.GetString(0);
                string nomeAluno = reader.GetString(1);
                string apelidoAluno = reader.GetString(2);
                string contactoAluno = reader.GetString(3);
                string emailAluno = reader.GetString(4);
            }
            int index = this.lstAlunos.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nome: " + nomeAluno);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces to the ends of the strings you're concatenating. Right now this segment:

```
            "columns" +
            "FROM" +
```

will give you "columnsFROM" which is obviously bad SQL.

Some other suggestions:

- Add error handling. The exception you got from this should give you a clue as to where the problem is.
- Use parameters instead of concatenating string values. It will protect you from SQL Injection attacks and take care of formatting for you.
- Don't use `ROW_NUMBER()` without some sore of explicit order. THere's no guarantee that you'll get the rows in the same order that they were saved in previously. Use an ID column instead.